# Transfer Metadata Only from a Production Org to another production Org (in trial)

Tags: metadata, data-export, instance

I saw others threads speaking about this topic but they didn't really help me or I must not have understood them!
I need to transfer a batch (the whole existing ORG) of metadata to a newly opened SF Organisation. NO Records should be imported, only the structure of the ORG (APPS; OBJS; fields; Automation; flows)

I am a SF admin not certified, with minimum exp. in Java, coding, and APIs.

I saw options speaking about Eclipse and ANT but I am facing numerous issues with those options (probably due to my lack of experience).

The process is fairly simple when is within the same instance but It gets so much complicated when instances are different. It must be a scenario that occurred thousands of times, there must be a faster workaround!

Is there a simple way (code-less) to get this done? From your personal experience, Is it something I can request through support or through the Account Manager? (if it works my company will purchase a new Instance after all)

thank you for your help and forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

to move metadata between orgs with clicks not code you can use change sets
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.changesets.htm&type=5

Comment: I get that, but in the case you suggested, metadata belongs to the same Org. I have to move it, ideally, from one production Org to another one (from one Org to another). Can I do that with 2 instances from different orgs ?

Comment: You cannot create deployment connections between arbitrary orgs, only between orgs that are affiliated to the same production Org.
So you can deploy using Change Sets between different sandboxes and the production org they are related to, but not between 2 different production orgs.
see this link : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.deploy_connection_parent.htm&type=5